# Max size of User and Venue Ids

Tags: foursquare

As a side project I am creating a connected app and was wondering what the max size for the user and venue ids were? Should I just do 'BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL' for user ids and 'VARBINARY(255)' for venue ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those both work. User IDs are 64-bit longs, and VARBINARY(255) will be sufficient for venue ids.